# Executing a rails action on a view regularly during every x amount of time (Interval)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous, view, intervals

I have a view, with a partial:

show:

```
<!-- This must happen at regular intervals  -->
<td><%= link_to edit_simulation_path(@simulation), @simulation, method: :put, id: @simulation.id, data: { remote: true }, :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs" %></td>

<%= render 'simulation' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', simulations_path %>
```

_simulation:

```
<div id="sim_div">
  <h1><%= @simulation.identifier %></h1>
  <h4>Dimensions: <%= @simulation.x_size %>x<%= @simulation.y_size %></h4>
  <h4>Verdict: <%= @simulation.verdict %></h4>

  <ul>
    <li> This should display the seating arrangement of the current simulation </li>
    <li> This should dispaly the verdict of the current state of the simulation </li>
    <li> It should automatically and asynchronously update itself to the next state at a regular interval.  </li>
  </ul>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @simulation.state.each do |row| %>
        <tr>
        <% row.each do |current| %>        
            <td class="text-center"><%= current %></td>        
          <% end%>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
</div>
```

Right now the button will asynchronously call update, updating the state of the simulation and refreshing the partial without refreshing the whole page.

The button `<!-- This must happen at regular intervals  -->` I want to run every x seconds, instead of being a clickable button. Instead just an action executing on a regular interval.

Doing something like this all I've been able to find online is using cron, but surely their must be an easier way of doing it (*And only when this view is open*).

Comment: Are you using jquery? I think the keyword you want to search for is "polling". You can use javascript to periodically perform ajax requests and update your page. For example : http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/polling-with-javascript-jquery/

Comment: Possibly, I'll take a look when I get home..

Comment: @Shadwell could you post your response as an answer so I can accept, its the route I'm taking.

Comment: It's not a great answer to be honest and best left as a comment. You can answer yourself with a bit more detail when you've solved it.